# Replace file in PHP

Tags: php, file, replace

I would like to replace one image file with another in PHP. Both have same name (123), but they are in different directory and should have different extension. I want to replace first image with second image.

1. ../images/123.gif
2. ../images/xxx/123.png

Is it possible with any function? Thank you.

Comment: Read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)?

Comment: Copying and overwriting the file with a different extension, you will have a GIF file masquerading as a PNG file. You would need to convert the image first.

Comment: I read manual and I found functions like copy(), rename() and unlink() but I dont know if this functions do the job correctly. Also I don't want to change extension, only delete first image and place there second image from different directory.

Comment: Have you got any code implementation for us to see?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got any code yet.

Comment: copy($old_file, $new_file);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moving, deleting, copying etc... are all basic *actions* that are needed whenever working with file systems. As such the documentation will undoubtedly have all of the information you need.

1. http://php.net/rename
2. http://php.net/copy
3. http://php.net/unlink

You say that you want to replace the first file with the second.. But you don't mention what you want to happen to the original copy of the second image?

If you rename (i.e. move) it then the file will no longer exist in it's starting location. If you want the file to remain in both directories then you should use `copy` instead.

In this case, all you need is:

```
rename('/path/to/get/file.from', '/path/to/put/file.to');
```

**NOTE:** You are able to use relative pats (e.g. `./` and `../`)

---

### Additional code

```
rename('/path/to/get/file.b', '/path/to/put/file.b');
unlink('/path/to/remove/file.a');
```

#### Working example

```
rename('../image/new/8.jpg', '../image/8.jpg'); //Moves new (jpg) file to `../image` directory
unlink('../image/8.gif');                       //Delete old file with gif extension
```

Comment: `rename('/path/to/get/image.jpg', '/path/to/put/image.gif');`
This will do what I want, but png image will have gif extension.

Comment: So what you want to do is move _file b_ from _directory b_ into _directory a_ and delete the first image with the same name (minus the extension)?

Comment: Check the updated answer (link to documentation and additional code). So you would rename it to the _correct file extension_

Comment: Probably yes, I think that you describe it well.

Comment: I tried it, but it also deletes moved image.

Comment: Can you show me what code you actually used?

Comment: `rename('../image/new/8.jpg', '../image/8.gif');
unlink('../image/8.gif');`

Comment: `rename('../image/new/8.jpg', '../image/8.jpg'); unlink('../image/8.gif');` -- You want to rename it to the same format!

Comment: I only want to not effect image extension.

Comment: See the code I've just added above to the answer... Hopefully that should clear things up :)

Comment: Solution: `unlink('../image/8.gif');

if (copy('../image/new/8.jpg', '../new/8.jpg')) {
  unlink('../image/new/8.jpg');`

Comment: That code does the same as `rename('../image/new/8.jpg', '../image/8.jpg'); unlink('../image/8.gif');` only longer...

Comment: Yes, even 2 solutions are available. :) I'm glad you help me!