# Overwrite custom css file with new css file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

As part of a custom made plugin users can customize the core CSS file, but as some noobs probably will mess up the CSS file I have build in an option that allows a user to reset the CSS file.

I am looking for a small php snippet which will copy the plugin_core_org.css file and will override the plugin_core.css file with it.

files structure

```
- css

-- plugin_core.css(users can edit this file only)

-- backup_files

--- plugin_core_org.css
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146954/replace-file-in-php)

Comment: Solved, used php copy for this....not sure if this is the best and safest wat to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll enqueue css files by wp_enqueue_style so you can do this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('custom-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/plugin_core.css');
wp_enqueue_style('original-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/plugin_core_org.css', array('custom-styles'));
```

The third attributte is dependences - handles in this array will be load before actual stylesheet.

More information about wp_enqueue_style you can find [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, as this will not replace(or override) the file.

Comment: I would do it by one custom_styles.css - where customers could add some styles and plugin_core.css - where are only yours styles. Customers shouldn't edit it here.

Comment: There is an custom CSS file, but I still allow users to access the main CSS file, that why I wanted to use an sort of reset option, if they mess up the core file they can reset the file. But I have found what I am looking for....php copy will do the trick.